# Extract a part of string using strict pattern match

Tags: regex, perl

```
DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|FIN{-1|0|-1|14|67|0|0}|IT[{"BON"|1|0}|{"RIG"|55152|99|39|0}]|DEP|ADM[{001|14|60|60|0|0|2|0|1|0|0}|{100|144178|60|7|0|0|2|0|50|0|0}]|DEP}
```

how can i extract the below string

```
IT[{"BON"|1|0}|{"RIG"|55152|99|39|0}]
```

my regex `(.)IT\\[\\{(.*?)\\}\\]` returns the full string

```
IT[{"BON"|1|0}|{"RIG"|55152|99|39|0}]|DEP|ADM[{001|14|60|60|0|0|2|0|1|0|0}|{100|144178|60|7|0|0|2|0|50|0|0}]
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/13 ?????????/

Comment: Your regex _should_ match the full string.  Use regex 101 site to debug.

Comment: but the perl i use in linux doesnt return the shortest match, i get the full match.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tim Biegeleisen the regex should match the full line - that's why there is ".*" to match everything before and after the pattern.

```
my $line ='DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|DEP|FIN{-1|0|-1|14|67|0|0}|IT[{"BON"|1|0}|{"RIG"|55152|99|39|0}]|DEP|ADM[{001|14|60|60|0|0|2|0|1|0|0}|{100|144178|60|7|0|0|2|0|50|0|0}]|DEP}';
$line =~ s/.*(IT\[.*?}\]).*/$1/g;
```